# What is the difference between Protego Horribilis and Protego Maxima?

Tags: harry-potter

What is the the difference between Protego Horribilis and Protego Maxima?

Flitwick used Protego Horribilis in Battle of Hogwarts to defend to castle.

Protego maxima is the standard, stronger version of Protego (not unlike Lumos Maxima).

The only difference I could find is that Protego Horribilis produces a wind-like effect.  Maybe the difference is in the range?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Newt say Lumos Maxima in the Fantastic Beasts trailer?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114726/why-does-newt-say-lumos-maxima-in-the-fantastic-beasts-trailer) ; especially, [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/114727/98028) tackles the difference between Horribilis and Maxima versions.

Comment: According to the references in Harry Potter wiki `protego maxima` is indirectly mentioned in the book, so I would think it's considered canon?

Comment: But I didnt know that that `lumos Maxima` is only movie canon, thanks